# PowerShell see if there is folders that match env:systemroot with longer names regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I testing if there is a folder named \windows\software and I'm using this powershell code, that work.

```
$PathBackup = Test-Path Env:\systemroot\software -IsValid
If ($PathBackup -eq $true) {Write-host "There is backup's"}
Else {write-Verbose "There is no backup's of folder \software*"}
```

But what i'm really wanted, is to test if there is any other folder that matches the \software******* folder and not the \software\ folder itself.

How can I do that with regular expression?

I have tried this, but with no luck:

```
$PathBackup = Test-Path Env:\systemroot\software -IsValid | Where { $_ -match '\w{8,}'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the most straight forward way would be use `Get-ChildItem` with wildcard globbing. Where `?` matches any character and `*` is zero or more of any character.

This will match \softwarebackup but not \software or \backupsoftware

```
 if (Get-ChildItem "$Env:SystemRoot\software?*") {
     Write-Verbose "There are backups"
 } else {
     Write-Verbose "There are no backups of folder \software*"
 }
```

This will match \softwarebackup, \software, and \backupsoftware

```
  if (Get-ChildItem "$Env:SystemRoot\*software*") {
      Write-Verbose "There are backups"
  } else {
      Write-Verbose "There are no backups of folder \software*"
  }
```

This will match \softwarebackup and \backupsoftware but not \software

```
  #Using Globbing

  if (@((Get-ChildItem "$Env:SystemRoot\software?*"),(Get-ChildItem "$Env:SystemRoot\?*software")) | Where-Object {$_}) {
      Write-Verbose "There are backups"
  } else {
      Write-Verbose "There are no backups of folder \software*"
  }

  #using regex

  if (Get-ChildItem "$Env:SystemRoot" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '.+software$|^software.+'}) {
      Write-Verbose "There are backups"
  } else {
      Write-Verbose "There are no backups of folder \software*"
  }
```

Comment: RegEX can be hard :-) - Thx. what if the folder can start with software* or *software*, how will the systemroot line then look like ?

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen `if (Get-ChildItem "$Env:SystemRoot\software*") ` would include `$Env:SystemRoot\software`

Comment: I dont want it to match systemroot\software\ but want it to match something like systemroot\backupsoftware\ or system\softwarebackup\ but not the stand alone \software\ :-)

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it's the best way to do it, but think I got it with:

```
$PathBackup = Test-Path Env:\systemroot\software -IsValid | Where { $_ -match 'software+\w'}
```